# Refactor my ruby snippet so it doesn't look like C anymore: method(method(param))

Tags: ruby

I have a class which uses a connection object to send the request data created by a request_builder object.

The code looks like this:
`connection.send_request(request_builder.build_request(customer))`

This in turn is called by 
`build_report(customer, connection.send_request(request_builder.build_request(customer)))`

Ugly! Any ideas on how to make it more expressive? Usually in ruby and OOP we chain objects like this: "string".make_it_bigger.flash_it.send

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code above. Passing parameters to methods is very much OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's code, that how it looks. But you can make yourself a favour by not trying to cram everything together on one line:

```
request = request_builder.build_request(customer)
response = connection.send_request(request)
report = build_report(customer, response)
```

if you told us more about your code base we might be able to suggest something else, but you don't give us very much to go on. What does the `request_builder` object do? Does `connection.send_request(...)` return a response? Why does a report need a customer and a response (assuming that's what is returned by `connection.send_request(...)`), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
build_report(customer, request_builder.build_request(customer).send_over(connection))
```